# Angular 4 errors trying to display object properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning Angular 4 on my own and having a hard time displaying an objects properties in the template.

I am using API to Get a single object by id. I can display the object using an *ngFor in the template and everything displays perfectly. However I get a console error "ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.". I don't want it to be an array but when I try "{{ course.courseTitle || 'Loading Data...' }}" on it's own it won't display anything.

course.ts

```
export interface Course {
  id?: number;
  courseCode?: string;
  courseTitle?: string;
  masterOU?: number;
  template?: number;
  textToSpeechScripts?: number;
  pages?: number;
  quizzes?: number;
  discussionForums?: number;
  assignments?: number;
}
```

pages.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService } from "../shared/dataService";
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router"
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { Course } from "../shared/entities/course";

@Component({
    selector: "pages",
    templateUrl: "pages.component.html",
    styleUrls:[]
})

export class PagesComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Course Pages';

    constructor(
        private data: DataService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {  }

    public course: Course;

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.course = {};
        this.course.id = this.route.snapshot.params['courseID']

        this.route.params
            .subscribe(
            (params: Params) => {
                this.course.id
            });

        this.data.loadPages(this.course.id)
            .subscribe(() => this.course = this.data.course);

        console.log(this.course.courseTitle)
    }
}
```

"console.log(this.course.courseTitle)" in the above file displays "undefined".

pages.component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
        <div *ngFor="let c of course">
        <p>{{ c.courseTitle || 'Loading Data...' }} - {{ c.courseCode || 'Loading Data...' }}</p>
    </div>

        <p>{{ course.id || 'Loading Data...' }}</p>

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

        <table ng-hide="course.pages == null" class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Page</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngFor="let c of course">
                <tr *ngFor="let p of c.pages">
                    <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ p.pageName }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a>View</a> |
                        <a>Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p><a [routerLink]="'/courses'">Back to List</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

dataService.ts

```
import { HttpModule, Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router"
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { AllCourses } from "./entities/allCourses";
import { Course } from "./entities/course";

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    public course: Course;

    loadPages(courseID): Observable<Course> {
        return this.http.get("/api/pages/course/" + courseID)
            .map((result: Response) => this.course = result.json());

    }

    saveNewPage(coursePageForm) {
        console.log(coursePageForm);
        return this.http.post("/api/pages/page", coursePageForm)

    }


}
```

console.log

```
ng:///AppModule/PagesComponent.ngfactory.js:55 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.webpackJsonp.../../../common/esm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngOnChanges (vendor.bundle.js:8756)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.bundle.js:60651)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.bundle.js:62182)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.bundle.js:62125)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.bundle.js:63018)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (vendor.bundle.js:62959)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/PagesComponent.ngfactory.js:100)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.bundle.js:62944)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:62091)
    at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:62442)
View_PagesComponent_0 @ ng:///AppModule/PagesComponent.ngfactory.js:55
ng:///AppModule/PagesComponent.ngfactory.js:55 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_
View_PagesComponent_0 @ ng:///AppModule/PagesComponent.ngfactory.js:55
ng:///AppModule/PagesComponent.ngfactory.js:78 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.webpackJsonp.../../../common/esm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngOnChanges (vendor.bundle.js:8756)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.bundle.js:60651)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.bundle.js:62182)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.bundle.js:62125)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.bundle.js:63018)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (vendor.bundle.js:62959)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/PagesComponent.ngfactory.js:103)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.bundle.js:62944)
    at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:62091)
    at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:62442)
View_PagesComponent_0 @ ng:///AppModule/PagesComponent.ngfactory.js:78
ng:///AppModule/PagesComponent.ngfactory.js:78 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_
```

I've tried to Google the issue but it's difficult since I'm a beginner and may not be using the correct terminology. What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Post what you have in console.log(this.course)

Comment: Try console.log(this.course[0].courseTitle); The result is wrapped inside an object/array

Comment: @Sajeetharan I've added console.log to my post above.

Comment: @Steve the API is only going to return a single object every time. I would like to not have to iterate through an array for that.

Comment: @RJay i need console.log of your array

Comment: @Sajeetharan It's "[{…}]
0
:
{id: 1, courseCode: "BUS 101", courseTitle: "Business 101", masterOU: 123456, template: null, …}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)"

I get that it is coming back as an array from the API call in my DataService.ts however it should just be a single object. I don't declare my class as an array so I would think it's not an array. I would like it to just be an individual object, not an array.

Answer (score -1):

Change this to:

```
this.route.params
        .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
            this.course.id = params['courseID']
        });
```

What is this doing and why is it rewriting the entire this.course object?

```
    this.data.loadPages(this.course.id)
        .subscribe(() => this.course = this.data.course);
```

Comment: loadPages is calling a method from my dataService.ts file. I've added that file to my post above.